# Why is the English word "studio" transcribed as スタジオ?

Tags: etymology, english-to-japanese, phonology, phonetics, transcription

So I'm aware that transcription into Japanese is not always clear-cut, and there are plenty of exceptions. It sort of makes sense that "Australia" is オーストラリア not *オーストレリア and "stadium" is スタジアム not *ステージアム, perhaps because those are partial transliteration, not pure transcription. But why is "studio" スタジオ? Shouldn't it be *at least* be something like *ストジオ? Or are dictionaries wrong about its actual etymology (i.e. from English)?

Answer (score 3):

The combination `tu` in some words is rendered as タ. As far as I can remember now, ト is not used.

- bathtub バスタブ
- study スタディー
- tuck タック
- tumbler タンブラー

In addition, [etymology of *studio* is the same as that of *study*](http://www.etymonline.com/word/studio) (from [Lantin *studium*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/studium#Latin)). To my ears, ストジオ and スタジオ are equally bad as the phonetic approximation of *studio*, but somehow スタジオ is at least understandable for those who already know the facts above. スツジオ might have been another possible option (*two* /tu/ is ツー, *tool* /tuːl/ is ツール), but I find it hard to pronounce.

Most people today understand the sounds /tu/ and /di/ that appear in loanwords (See: [What "non-standard" katakana are commonly used?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19201/5010)), but these were not available in the past. Had this word been introduced firstly in the 21 century, it would have been ストゥディオ.

Comment: /di/ > ジ makes sense, because ジ natively occurs. But /tu:/ > タ doesn't really, unless it was confused with "study". Then again スタディ is not even used that much (not found in Kokugo Daijiten, barely legit-looking in other dictionaries), and it contains ディ not ジ, so it could either be a mere rendition (not an actual word), or an actual word but a much more recent one.

Comment: Coincidentally, stadium is romanized as スタジアム and not ステージアム. There are just some loanwords that do not necessarily follow an expected spelling pronunciation.