# Attempts to distinguish English "L" and "R" sounds using (extended) katakana

Tags: pronunciation, katakana, orthography, loanwords, history

Katakana can represent many foreign sounds that do not exist in native Japanese words, either by using special characters such as ヴ or by using special katakana combinations such as フュ. They are collectively called "[extended katakana](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19201/5010)", although few native speakers know this term. Thanks to them, young Japanese people can learn to pronounce foreign words more or less closely to their original pronunciation. Although they may not be perfect, フューチャー is a lot better than ヒューチャー and レモンティー is a lot better than レモンチー. Few Japanese people mistake 'Venus' as 'Benus' because it is commonly spelt as ヴィーナス in katakana.

However, I am not aware of any previous attempts to distinguish, for example, English 'read' and 'lead' using modified/extended katakana. Come to think of it, this seems strange to me. Japanese people have invented special kana to express [Okinawan sounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okinawan_scripts#Basic_syllables_and_kai-y%C5%8Don_(palatalized_syllables)), [Ainu sounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_language#Special_katakana_for_the_Ainu_language) and [bidakuon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakuten_and_handakuten#Phonetic_shifts), so I think there must have been similar attempts also for the English sound pairs that are known to be difficult to Japanese speakers.

Questions:

1. Historically, were there any attempts to distinguish "L" and "R", "S" and "TH", etc., using katakana? How commonly were they used? It could be special katakana like "ラ with (han)dakuten" or "small ラ", and it could be special combinations like "ゥラ".
2. If there were such attempts in the past, why were they all unsuccessful despite obvious advantages? I doubt "because they looked unnatural" is a good reason here, because ティ and ヴ should have looked equally unreasonable and unnatural at first.

I know some recent English dictionaries targeted at Japanese middle school students [use **hiragana** らりるれろ/さしすせそ to denote the sound of R and TH](http://bloge-de-english.com/newhorizon). I also found [this 2ch thread](http://viper.2ch.sc/test/read.cgi/news4vip/1507467565/), which was not really helpful.

Comment: Making a reasonable (even backwards compatible) proposal for distinguishing these is not too difficult. (I presume you came across [this PDF](http://www.geocities.jp/newkatakana/newkatakana.pdf)?) The real question is your question 2: "why hasn't it happened yet?"

Comment: No I didn't know this PDF, so this may be counted as one attempt in the past :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *If there were such attempts in the past, why were they all unsuccessful despite obvious advantages? I doubt "because they looked unnatural" is a good reason here, because ティ and ヴ should have looked equally unreasonable and unnatural at first.*

ご質問の中で挙げられていた「フュ」「ティ」「ヴ」などのような仮名の拡張と、問題になっている「L/R」「S/TH」を区別するための拡張は、同列には扱えないように思えます。

参考のために、国語審議会の「[外来語の表記](http://www.mext.go.jp/b_menu/hakusho/nc/t19910207001/t19910207001.html)」の付表を掲げます。
[image]

この表の左半分がいわゆる伝統的な五十音表、右側が「拡張」された音節<sup>1</sup>に当たると思いますが、それらも外来音に応じて自由自在に作れるわけではなく、**五十音表に含まれる現代（共通語）発音における子音の音声と母音の音声、およびその直拗音、清濁の操作を組み合わせて生成可能な音節**しか作られていないことがわかります<sup>2</sup>。五十音表の並びは活用などの文法的な交替をよく説明しますが、一方でよく知られているように、例えばタ行と呼ばれるタ ([[t]])・チ ([[tɕ]])・ツ ([[ts]])・テ ([[t]])・ト ([[t]])には音声的に相当異なった子音が混在しています<sup>3</sup>。上図右欄にあるような音節は、それらの子音を独立した音素とみなして母音との対応表を作った時に、既存の五十音では書き表せない「穴」を埋める位置に存在しています<sup>4</sup>。つまり現代日本語では音韻論的な音節構造はすでにこれらの拡張を許容する形に組み換えられつつあり、形態論の想定する音節構造と乖離し始めているために、五十音表側からみると「拡張」した音節ないしは表記があるように見えるということができます。

ここで最初に挙げた例を見ると、

- **ティ**：「テ」の子音 //t// + 「イ」 //i//<sup>5</sup>
- **フュ**：「フ」の子音 //ɸ// + 拗音 //j// + 「ウ」 //u// （→実質的に「フ」の拗音）
- **ヴ**：「フ」 //ɸu// の濁音 //βu//
  （補足：ヴは英語などの [[v]] を表すものと考えられがちですが、フと同様、実際は唇歯音で発音されません。またこの音はバ行が語中で弱化した発音に近くなるため、バ・ヴァ行の弁別が不十分になることも、この綴りの許容度が弱い原因だと思われます）

として一応「日本語の音韻論の範囲内」で説明可能です。

また、アイヌ語仮名や新沖縄文字についても言及されていました（他にも[ケセン語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B1%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E8%AA%9E)の[仮名](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Umihotaru/comment/20110924)や[台湾語仮名](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%B0%E6%B9%BE%E8%AA%9E%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D)、[八重山方言用仮名](https://www.unicode.org/L2/L2016/16354-kana-small-ltr.pdf)などもあります）が、これらは先ほどの例とはまた別枠で、いわば**仮名文字の社会言語学的威信が強い範囲内でありながら、対象言語を忠実に書き表すために（標準）日本語話者への理解度を度外視して策定されたもの**だと思います。つまりこれらの大胆な仮名の拡張が行われる背景には、その言語の正書法を仮名で記すことが「当然」だと思われるほどの社会的な状況が必要だということです。

以上を踏まえて、L/RやS/THの区別について考えると、

1. //l//, //r// や //s//, //θ// を区別するような子音の対立が日本語の本土方言に存在したことは有史以来確認されていないし、現存もしない。したがって一般の日本語話者にとっては「ティ」などのように母語の音素を応用して自然に生成される音とは認知されない。
2. 戦前を含め、日本の支配が及んだ領域に //l//, //r// や //s//, //θ// を区別する言語が乏しく<sup>6</sup>、正書法として分けて書き表す需要が生じなかったために、公的・私的にこれらの音を区別するような仮名の拡張が行われなかった。

というような感じだと思っています。

---

<sup>1: 右欄は第1表に属するものと第2表に属するものがありますが、右上にあるものは「**ちぇ**すとー」や「おとっ**つぁ**ん」など本土日本語の範疇で使われることがあって外来の音節と切り捨てることができなかったものだと思われます（ただし共通語ではまれ）。

2: 例えば英語は子音だけではなく、日本語よりもはるかに多くの母音も区別しますが、それらを表すために母音の段を増やした表記を作った、という例は寡聞にして知りません。日本語の母音体系自体には何ら手が加えられていないということです。

3: 厳密にいえば音声的にはタ・テ・トそれぞれの子音も調音位置が異なります。"ti"のような音を表すのに「タィ」や「トィ」ではなく「ティ」が選ばれているのもテの子音がイ段に一番近いからと思われます。

4: クァ・グァ行は現代の発音から導くのは困難ですが、この発音自体はア段に限っていえば「[合拗音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8B%97%E9%9F%B3#%E5%90%88%E6%8B%97%E9%9F%B3_2)」として19世紀まで残存していました（cf. [怪談](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%80%AA%E8%AB%87_(%E5%B0%8F%E6%B3%89%E5%85%AB%E9%9B%B2))）。

5: イ段の母音は直音か拗音か微妙なところであり、直拗音の区別がない、あるいは両系統共用の母音と解釈することもできます。ただし「スィ」と「シ」のような例もあります。

6: 一般に東～東南アジアの言語で //θ// を持つ言語はまれで（[ミャンマー語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%9E%E8%AA%9E)にはあり）、日本が統治した地域ではわずかに台湾先住民族の[サオ語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%AA%E8%AA%9E)にあるようです。また同範囲で[流音](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B5%81%E9%9F%B3)を複数持つ言語は、[満州語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%BA%80%E5%B7%9E%E8%AA%9E)や旧委任統治領の[パラオ語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AA%E8%AA%9E)や[マーシャル語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AB%E8%AA%9E)などに限られており、当時の研究資料が少なく仮名表記策定にまで至っていなかったものと思われます。</sup>

Comment: Okay, so the point is that the Japanese language *for the general public* has never introduced a totally new consonant. Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: @naruto Right. *Kana for Japanese language* has never introduced a sound *which Japanese language speakers have never utter*.

Answer (score 5):

[This PDF](http://www.geocities.jp/newkatakana/newkatakana.pdf) has the following proposal, using the existing diacritic *handakuten* to create

> - a modified ラ行 (ラﾟリﾟルﾟレﾟロﾟ) and modified *chōonpu* ーﾟ indicating R //r//, leaving the usual ラ行 representing L //l//

as well as

> - a modified サ行 (サﾟシﾟスﾟセﾟソﾟ) representing unvoiced TH //θ//
> - a modified ザ行 (ザﾟジﾟズﾟゼﾟゾﾟ) representing voiced TH //ð//

(as well as a few other conventions).

Examples would be

> - フライ ↔ フラﾟイ
> - フリー ↔ フリﾟー
> - サーﾟヴィス
> - スﾟルﾟー

It has the advantage that

1. it uses existing typography and can already be implemented using U+FF9F HALFWIDTH KATAKANA SEMI-VOICED SOUND MARK  `ﾟ`, and
2. these are almost "backwards compatible" to the usual *katakana* representation — in most cases you can simply ignore the *handakuten*.

Comment: (Just stumbled across this Q&A.)  It's been ten years since Hoshino wrote that proposal.  Any indication of whether her ideas are getting any traction?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi No indications as far as I can tell. It might be a reasonable proposal, but getting things to change is surely difficult. There ought to be some friction ("why introduce more complicated notation?") as well as big inertia (essentially all existing written works as well as the minds of all native speakers). I wonder what the motivation/process for the change バ・ビ・ブ・ベ・ボ → ヴァ・ヴィ・ヴ・ヴェ・ヴォ was.

Comment: I haven't read through it closely -- wasn't that just to differentiate `/b/` and `/v/` in borrowings?  Like バイオテクノロジー vs. ヴァイオリン?

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Right. I don't know much about the history of this change バ → バ・ヴァ. The proposal by Hoshino is very similar (differentiating //r// & //l//, //s// & //θ// and //z// & //ð// in borrowings) so looking at the history of the バ → バ・ヴァ change one might be able to see what it takes to implement such a proposal.